# Multiple Windows in Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to have multiple windows-"handles" open in one Adobe AIR application? You can ofcourse make a walkaround by letting the app be transparent, but I am interested in a better solution.

Comment: what's with the logo in the tags ? I thoughts were just text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick (It is Theo's code just corrected a bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" applicationComplete="main()">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.core.Window;

    private function main( ) : void {
        var window:Window;
        for ( var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            window = new Window();
            window.width  = 200;
            window.height = 300;
            window.open(true);
            window.showStatusBar = false;
        }
    }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to handle this is to make the main class a subclass of `Application` instead of `WindowedApplication`, and set the `initialWindow`s `visible` setting to `false`. Then, in your main class you create as many `Window` instances as you want.

Main class:

```
<Application xmlns="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <applicationComplete>main()</applicationComplete>
  <Script>
  <![CDATA[
  private function main( ) : void {
    var window : Window;
    for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      window = new Window();
      window.width  = 200;
      window.height = 300;
      window.open(true);
    }
  }
  ]]>
  </Script>
</Application>
```

App config:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5">
  ...
  <initialWindow>
    ...
    <visible>false</visible>
  </initialWindow>
</application>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand you could you post some very basic mxml/as3 code?

Comment: Are you using Flash-builder? Because the Flex 4 SDK won't accept it. It returns G:\FOREX\src\Main.mxml(6):  Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Window.

Comment: Could you rewrite you sample to as3? There I can import Window etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want window "handles" ?

The PopupManager lets you create non-modal windows.

Cheers

Comment: I don't want an "in application" window. I want a completely new native window.

Comment: You want an AIR application to create GUI objects outside the AIR runtime?

I think that goes against the idea of AIR: a contained, managed application environment that has limited access and interaction with the OS.

Cheers